# CoreDeviceMotion does not work to update physics world gravity

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, core-motion, skphysicsworld

I am trying to get the device motion data and change the gravity direction, so that when I tilt my iPhone, the ball will move in the tilt direction. In this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76740/make-game-like-space-invaders-sprite-kit-and-swift-tutorial-part-1) the method is getting acceleration data and applyForce on the node. However, I would like to achieve this goal by changing the gravity direction (no matter how I tilt the phone, the gravity is always along the real physical gravity direction).

Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion
class GameScene: SKScene {
let ballName = "redBall"
var gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0,-9.8)


let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
let motion = CMDeviceMotion()

func addBall(){
    //Create the ball
    var ball = SKShapeNode()
    var path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 0, 0, 45, 0, CGFloat(M_PI * 2), true)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
    ball.name = ballName
    ball.path = path
    ball.lineWidth = 2.0
    ball.fillColor = SKColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 0.9)
    ball.position = CGPoint(x:size.width/2, y: size.height)

    //Set the ball's physcial properties
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.frame.width/2)
    ball.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    ball.physicsBody!.mass = 0.1
    ball.physicsBody!.friction = 0.2
    ball.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.9
    ball.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true

    self.addChild(ball)
}

func gravityUpdated(){
    let vector = CGVectorMake(CGFloat(motion.gravity.x), CGFloat(motion.gravity.y))
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = vector
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: view.frame)
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = gravityDirection
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()
    addBall()
}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    gravityUpdated()
}
}
```

In the above code I use CMDeviceMotion to get the gravity data, and give the gravity value to the physicsWorld.gravity. The app always crashes when I run it.

Xcode indicates there is a bug in gravityUpdate() function, but I can't find it. Hope someone can help me solve this problem. Or provide me a better way to simulate the gravity. Thanks!

Comment: in gravityUpdated .... try to replace this `motion.gravity.x` with this `motionManager. deviceMotion.gravity.x`... for Y do the same

Comment: post the crash message and line where it crashes, xcode highlights that line (unless xcode itself crashes as well due to swift's buggy debugger)

Comment: @TonyMkenu I tried this, still crash.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D The line where it crashes is the first of gravityUpdated() `let vector = CGVectorMake(CGFloat(motion.gravity.x), CGFloat(motion.gravity.y))`. There is no crash message. After I changed this line as @TonyMkenu says, there is a crash message: **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out myself. It's necessary to check if the motion data is available before give it value to physicsworld.gravity.

Here is the new code:

```
func gravityUpdated(){
    if let data = motionManager.deviceMotion {
        let gravity = data.gravity
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(CGFloat(gravity.x), CGFloat(gravity.y))
    }
}
```

Note that if no device-motion data is available, the value of the property is nil. 
[CMMotionManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/deviceMotion)